# Using bundle command when running Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bundle

Having a play with Jenkins and i have come to a point where I get an error

```
# execute shell

bundle exec rubocop \

# returns

/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/hudson7349521107935402055.sh: line 2: bundle: command not found
```

I have bundle installed at

```
/Users/lewis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/bundle
```

When running jenkins it runs as the `Jenkins` user so am i right in thinking it wouldn't know where to find bundle ? How can i remedy this so that i can use the bundle command with jenkins?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Install RVM as the jenkins user.

Comment: thanks, so just `sudo su jenkins` and then install rvm ?

Comment: so when installing rvm as the jenkins user i get `ERROR: '/usr/local/bin' is not writable`, so rvm is installed as me (so my user) would installing as the jenkins user cause any conflicts ?

Comment: You may have to check permissions to make sure they are executable by both your user name and Jenkins. In fact, you may not need to reinstall as long as permissions are setup correctly.